# Windows 10 - Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) Extended Advertising

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

Does Windows 10 natively support discovery and pairing with Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) Extended Advertising?

[image]

Comment: BLE has two advertising methods Legacy (introduced in 4.0) and Extended (introduced in 5.0). I read through your link, and didn't see any mention of the new Extended Advertising. https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-5-advertisements/

Comment: AFAIK itdoe snot. Officially Win 10 does not support Bluetooth 5 yet.